# Provide scripts through cocoapods

Tags: cocoapods

I've got a cocoapod that contains some shell-scripts that's shared between some projects.

However, the scripts are only needed in the build-phase. How should I include them in the podspec?

If I use `source_files = ...`, Xcode will complain about "Warning: no rule process file '..' of type text.script.sh for architecture x86_64"

If I use `resource` or `resources` it will be copied into the target bundle, which I don't want either.

Is there any way to achieve this?